# Finding a battery for an old e-bike

Tags: electric-bike, replacement, battery

I have an old Raleigh stow e way folding bike e-bike but sadly the battery has died. I’ve tried to replace it but can only find used ones on eBay which might not last long.

Battery is labelled:

```
Li-ion 10INR19/66-2
36V == 6.8AH   244.8WH
BL21   TranzX
```

[image: Modern version of same bike - stock image]

Comment: What’s your locality? . The pack seems to be a repurposed Segway unit, if you search on the part number “10INR19/66-2” there seems to be plenty of new units. Like this https://scooterguys.co.uk/product/genuine-segway-ninebot-36v-5100ah-5-1ah-internal-battery-sg5101

Comment: @WarrenBurton good find - OP should confirm on dimensions etc, because original is labeled 6.8 Ah and that listing is 5.1 Ah.  Might be a coincidence on the model number?    Based on https://www.raleigh.co.uk/gb/en/stow-e-way-folding-electric-bike/  the battery is definitely "TranzX 250wh 36V 6.8Ah Battery"   and is worth around 350 UKP  https://electricgarageshop.co.uk/p/standard-300wh-battery-for-the-raleigh-stow-e-way

Comment: Might be a coincidence on the part number as the capacity doesn’t match. Still if OP is in UK then there seems to be plenty of options to either buy new or get the old one refurbished.

Comment: I've added a stock photo of this bike.  If yours is substantially different, please do add a photo of your bike with [edit]   A photo of the battery might help too.

Answer (score 4):

In most cities there are companies that repack battery packs for all sorts of electronics. Most advertise around from power tools battery pack refurbishment but can probably refurbish yours.  You can also do it yourself if you are inclined, although it takes some skills working with electronics and the consequences of it going wrong makes it hard to recommended DIY.

Most battery backs use standard lithium cells 18650's being the most common. Refurbishing means replacing the dead cells with new ones. If looking into doing this be careful to find a reputable source. The cells themselves come in various qualities, and many will refurbish with tested used cells - a great way to save money and acceptable if those savings are passed on to the customer who is aware of what they are paying for.

Personally, if I could not find a new pack, I would go for a refurbishment from a local company offering long warrantees, using new cells from a reputable manufacturer (Samsung/Sony/Panasonic/LG etc). Do not do shop on price. Fake cells, using used cells claiming they are new, and dodgy workmanship are all possible (if not likely in some locations).

Answer (score 1):

If your battery pack is integrated into the downtube, or any other vendor-specific part that is integral to your bike, see @mattnz 's answer.
If your battery pack sits on the baggage rack, or has an other type of detachable holder, then you can replace it with any other battery pack that provides the correct voltage. You may need to salvage the plug that connects the original battery holder to the controller or motor.

The battery holder, unless it's integrated into the frame, is just an attachment point, and can be replaced together with the battery, if the original format is no longer available.

You can find ebike battery packs for 24, 36 or 48 Volt systems all over the internet. You might even get lucky finding one with the correct plug, but failing that, salvaging the one from your original battery holder is an option.